# unable to evaluate line from file as input aithmetically

Tags: bash, shell-script, files

So I am writing a bash script that takes in a file with integers on each line and I am writing a function that converts those integers in each line into roman numerals, which i will need to write into another file (I will do this using >>). The bulk of the work is done by the functions SubValue and RomanCon, RomanCon loops through the lines read from the file and convert it into a roman number, whilst subvalue just basically substitute the value from the integer into a roman numeral. These two when I do input an integer directly from a command line it works fine. However when I try to read from file input it does not work properly as it kept on saying integer expression expected despite the lines from my file purely being made up of integers.
I have tried using the double parentheis(()) and other force type -i however that still did not result in what I want.

Thank you

```
#!/bin/bash
#https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/converting-decimals-roman-numerals-bash
#https://opensource.com/article/21/3/input-output-bash
#https://phoenixnap.com/kb/bash-read-file-line-by-line
#https://www.tutorialspoint.com/linux_admin/linux_admin_reading_and_writing_to_files.htm
#https://github.com/joric/interviewbit/blob/master/scripting/regex-and-functions/convert-integer-to-roman-number.md

SubValue()
{
  # add $2 to romanvalue and subtract $1 from decvalue

  romanvalue="${romanvalue}$2"
  decvalue=$(($decvalue - $1 ))
}


RomanCon()
{
    decvalue=$1
    while [ "$decvalue" -gt 0 ] ; do
        if [ "$decvalue" -ge 1000 ] ; then
            SubValue 1000 "m"
        elif [ "$decvalue" -ge 900 ] ; then
            SubValue 900 "cm"
        elif [ "$decvalue" -ge 500 ] ; then
            SubValue 500 "d"
        elif [ "$decvalue" -ge 400 ] ; then
            SubValue 400 "cd"
        elif [ "$decvalue" -ge 100 ] ; then
            SubValue 100 "c"
        elif [ "$decvalue" -ge 90 ] ; then
            SubValue 90 "xc"
        elif [ "$decvalue" -ge 50 ] ; then
            SubValue 50 "l"
        elif [ "$decvalue" -ge 40 ] ; then
            SubValue 40 "xl"
        elif [ "$decvalue" -ge 10 ] ; then
            SubValue 10 "x"
        elif [ "$decvalue" -ge 9 ] ; then
            SubValue 9 "ix"
        elif [ "$decvalue" -ge 5 ] ; then
            SubValue 5 "v"
        elif [ "$decvalue" -ge 4 ] ; then
            SubValue 4 "iv"
        elif [ "$decvalue" -ge 1 ] ; then
            SubValue 1 "i"
        fi
    done
    echo $romanvalue
}

file=$1
while read -r line; do
    RomanCon $line
done <$file
```

I am running the script currently with the command line argument:

```
./roman.sh rome.txt
```

Yes I know I am not fulfilling the writing to a file component however this has not worked thus far as whenever I run it, it keeps on outputting:

```
: integer expression expected

: integer expression expected

: integer expression expected

: integer expression expected
```

Hence I do not know how to take those inputs (which is a file containing integers like:

```
1111
2345
789
905
```

Comment: show the exact result you get and how you're running the script

Comment: yep, the truncated error message with the colon at the left is a tell-tale sign of carriage return in the data moving the output position back. Use `dos2unix` as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

The errors are typically those that your script would emit if the input contained data from a DOS-formatted text file.  When read by a Unix shell script, each line from such a file would consist of some text, like `1111`, followed by a carriage-return character (part of what DOS text files use for encoding newlines).  The carriage-return character will be part of the data read into the `line` variable in your loop, and this value can therefore not be used as an integer later in the code.

Convert your input to a Unix text file using the `dos2unix` utility.

Another issue with your code is that the `romanvalue` variable is continuously concatenated with more and more Roman numerals.  You should reset it in each iteration of your main loop.

Making these changes to your code and input data, the following will be the output of your script with the given input:

```
mcxi
mmcccxlv
dcclxxxix
cmv
```

Comment: Thank you so much I will try that, you sir are a live safer though